# How can I create Author Template in Playground 4.4.1

Tags: swift-playground

I created a Playground project for Swift Studwent Challenge. (Playgorund 4.4.1). However, I am using Playground version 4.4.1. I could not create the Authr template via Playground application. I'm using Xcode 15.

I found this but.. Minimum Xcode 14.1

https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=Swift%20Playgrounds%20Author%20Template

[image]